# Extracting data from JSON Format in Google Big Query

Tags: json, google-bigquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to Extract data from JSON Format column in my power bi,
I'm using data source 'Google Big Query' in backend

I have a JSON Format in `data` column, it is in below format

```
ARRAY<STRUCT<
  id STRING,
  status STRING,
  name ARRAY<STRUCT<code STRING, value STRING>>,
  description ARRAY<STRUCT<code STRING, value STRING>>
>>
```

I need to extract data from `data` column which will be in below format and that column should be called as `data.name`

```
ARRAY<STRUCT<code STRING, value STRING>>
```

Please Help!

Thanks in advance

```
(SELECT MAX(name.value) FROM UNNEST(c.data_) AS data
cross join UNNEST(data.name) as name
where name.code in ('en')) as data
```

I tried like above, but it's not giving output correctly

Answer (score 0):

There is a need to parse JSON before using unnest:

```sql
WITH test_tbl as (
  Select 
    1 as colA, 
    JSON '''
      [{"id":"id1","status":"done",
        "name":[{"code":"c5","value":"5"},{"code":"c7","value":"7"}]},
      {"id":"id2",
        "name":[{"value":"9"}]} ]
      ''' as data
),
tbl as (
SELECT *,
json_extract_scalar(data_unnest.id) as id,
json_extract_scalar(data_name_unnest.value) as output_name
 from test_tbl
,unnest(json_extract_array(data)) as data_unnest,
unnest(json_extract_array(data_unnest.name)) as data_name_unnest
)

Select *,
max(output_name)  over () as output_name_max
from tbl~~~
```